# Most efficient way to take log of numpy array but ignore 0's

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, logarithm

I'd like to take the natural logarithm of a numpy array but not calculate the logarithm of 0-entries at all. I.e. I'd like to implement the convention log(0)=0 over numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
foo = np.random.rand(500)
%timeit np.log(foo)
%timeit np.log(foo,where=foo>0)
```

For the first call, this yields

> The slowest run took 12.63 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 100000 loops, best
>   of 3: 2.06 µs per loop

For the second call, we get

> The slowest run took 8.35 times longer than the
>   fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   100000 loops, best of 3: 4.31 µs per loop

So avoiding the 0's (even if there are no zeros in the array in this case) is much more expensive. This is clearly different if we look at sparse arrays, but is there a more efficient way to avoid zeros even in the non-sparse case?

Comment: I can't really reproduce that. And in your example you define `foo` and then use `bar`.

Comment: @MitchWheat: you have to consider it in the context of information theory, where we often encounter situations like 0 log 0 in the calculation of entropy.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: thanks, I corrected the variables. Cod runs fine on my side.

Comment: What I can't reproduce are the timings. Maybe your leftover `bar` happened to be a scalar?

Comment: *"you have to consider it in the context of information theory, where we often encounter situations like 0 log 0 in the calculation of entropy."*  In that case, take a look at [`scipy.special.xlogy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html) and [`scipy.special.entr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.entr.html).

Comment: Timings for me on 1.13.1 show that `where` takes 1.6x longer than without, on your benchmark

Comment: For me (1.13.3) it's more like `1.25x`. I'm doing `timeit('np.log(a, where=a>0)', setup='a=np.random.rand(500)', globals=globals(), number=100000)` and the same without 'where'.

Comment: Updated to numpy 1.14 and ran the same tests on the command line instead of spyder. The difference is still about a factor 1.7. Running python 2.7.13 (Anaconda custom (x86_64)). Any ideas on speeding this up?

Comment: What about @WarrenWeckesser's suggestion? Doesn't that crack it for you?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't apply in this situation, but the script.special.xlogy function is generally very interesting. It appears to me that there are no proposals to do the requested operation any faster. I'll wait a few days and otherwise mark my own post as answer.

Comment: If you're willing to add numba as a dependency, a post-jitted direct implementation of the manual loop with a branch was within 10% of np.log at small N and actually faster for me at large N.  Might be worth looking at.